# If a value already exists in sql database, create new values until a unique one comes up

Tags: php, pdo

since I need to generate a unique "id" for each user, I needed to check if this randomly generated id already existed in the database, and if it did, to create a new id and repeat the action until a unique id is found. Now, I don't know whether I did this correctly or not because I don't have a way of checking that, can anybody tell me if I did this correctly, and if not, what part should I change?

Here's my php code:

```php
  $bytes = '15';
  $secondary_id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));
  $stm_reg3 = $conn->prepare('SELECT secondary_id FROM users WHERE secondary_id = :secondary_id LIMIT 1');
  $stm_reg3->bindParam(":secondary_id", $secondary_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stm_reg3->execute();
  $row3 = $stm_reg3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( ! $row 3) {
while ( ! $row3) {
  $secondary_id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));
  $stm_reg3->execute();
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  It sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: @devlincarnate How would you suggest that he generate a unique random string?

Comment: @Barmar:  Google for `php generate unique random string`, for starts...and consider letting the db handle the "id" generation instead of php.

Comment: If you roll  your own be careful for race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$stm_reg3->fetch()` after `$stm_reg3->execute()` every time through the `while` loop. You can combine them into one call.

```
$bytes = '15';
$secondary_id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));
$stm_reg3 = $conn->prepare('SELECT secondary_id FROM users WHERE secondary_id = :secondary_id LIMIT 1');
$stm_reg3->bindParam(":secondary_id", $secondary_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
while ($stm_reg3->execute() && $stm_reg3->fetch()) {
    $secondary_id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));
}
```